# Generating well-formed nested stack push and pop operations

Tags: python, combinatorics

I am working on a project that uses a simple stack, and operations on said stack.

The operations include:

```
NoOp    # Do nothing, leave stack as-is
Push(i) # Push value i onto stack
Pop(i)  # Pop top value of stack, raise if popped value != i or stack is empty
```

I have a function that takes a sequence of these instructions, and executes them in order, starting with an empty stack. The final stack is then returned. A sequence that returns an empty stack is considered well-formed, in my case.

Examples of well-formed sequences:

```
() # The empty sequence
NoOp
Push(x), Pop(x)
Push(x), NoOp, NoOp, NoOp, Pop(x), NoOp # NoOps are OK sprinkled anywhere
Push(x), Push(y), Pop(y), Pop(x) # Nesting is OK
```

Examples of **not** well-formed sequences:

```
Push(x) # Does not leave an empty stack
Pop(x) # Attempt to pop from empty stack
Push(x), Push(y), Pop(x), Pop(y) # Improper nesting, Pop(x) will get y and error
```

For testing purposes, I'd like to be able to generate all well-formed sequences of instructions for a given max length N. Is there a way I can accomplish this using itertools without generating **all** permutations of sequences and filtering out the invalid ones?

Comment: I don't think `Push(x), Push(y), Pop(x), Pop(y)` would be improper—how does the stack know the name of the variable that was pushed? Seems like that sequence might even be a useful way of swapping the value of two variables.

Comment: Seems like an easy way to filter out (otherwise) invalid sequences would be to simply initialize a counter to zero, and then iterate through the sequence and increment the counter every time a `Push` is seen and decrement it whenever there's a `Pop`. If the counter ever goes negative, it's an invalid sequence (ignoring any `NoOp`s). The counter should also be zero at the end.

Comment: I'm using the variable names as a placeholder for equivalent values. I need to process the top elements of the stack before any lower ones, hence Push X, Push Y, Pop Y, Pop X. Popping and processing X before Y would be a logical error for my use case.

Comment: How do you expect anyone to be able to tell you how to generate any (much less all) "well-formed"  sequences when you haven't defined what one is along with all the "rules"?

Comment: I had included the rules in comments in my original code, I'm not sure where the confusion is? Perhaps an easier way of thinking of it would be nesting different kinds of brackets. [ { } ] is fine, but [ { ] } would not be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so we can do this by recursion.

The base case is if there are no elements.

If we look at the possible patterns we can see that all cases either start with NoOps or Push.

1. NoOps -> followed by the sequence of N-1
2. Push. Push is different in that it must be followed by a pop. But you notice you can notice the only sequences are push(x) - some sequence - pop(x) - some sequence. Note that some sequence could be empty or could have N-2 elements

From these ideas, we can come up with the following algorithm.

```
x = 0


def combinations(N):
    global x
    result = []     # A list of all the combinations of length N

    # Base case
    if N == 0:
        return [""]

    # Cases with NoOps followed by some sequence
    last_part=combinations(N-1)
    for i in last_part:
        result.append("NoOp, " + i)

    # Cases with Push(x) - some sequence - Pop(x) - some sequence
    if N > 1:
        for i in range(1, N):
            part1 = combinations(i-1)
            part2 = combinations(N-i-1)
            for j in part1:
                for k in part2:
                    result.append("Push(" + str(x) + "), " + j + "Pop("+ str(x) + "), " + k)
                    x += 1
    return result

# This is just to test. Change N to whatever it needs to be.
result = combinations(4)
for line in result:
    print(line)
```

For N=4 it will return:

- NoOp, NoOp, NoOp, NoOp,
- NoOp, NoOp, Push(0), Pop(0),
- NoOp, Push(1), Pop(1), NoOp,
- NoOp, Push(2), NoOp, Pop(2),
- Push(4), Pop(4), NoOp, NoOp,
- Push(5), Pop(5), Push(3), Pop(3),
- Push(6), NoOp, Pop(6), NoOp,
- Push(8), NoOp, NoOp, Pop(8),
- Push(9), Push(7), Pop(7), Pop(9),

***Edit - For getting all results from 0...N***

I think a comment someone was trying to make was that you may want not just the results for N returned, but for 0...N. Add this line:

```
result += combinations(N-1)
```

before the return statement. For N == 2 It will return:

- NoOp, NoOp,
- NoOp,
- Push(0), Pop(0),
- NoOp,
- ""

Comment: Thanks! This was very helpful as a starting point to get my own version up and running. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, thanks to Stef's answer, I was able to construct a generator approach that works perfectly.

```
def yield_sum_splits(n: int) -> typ.Iterable[typ.Tuple[int, int]]:
    """Given an integer, returns all possible sum splits.
    For any given split (a, b), a + b will always equal n.

    For example:
        5   -> (0, 5), (1, 4), (2, 3), (3, 2), (4, 1), (5, 0)
        -5  -> (0, -5), (-1, -4), (-2, -3), (-3, -2), (-4, -1), (-5, 0)
    """
    sign = int(math.copysign(1, n))
    an = abs(n)
    for i in range(an + 1):
        yield (sign * i, sign * (an - i))


def yield_valid_stack_cmd_seqs(length: int) -> typ.Iterable[str]:
    """Lazily yields valid stack command sequences.

    Valid stack command sequences are properly nested and balanced.
    """
    counter = itertools.count(start=0)

    def helper(n: int) -> typ.Iterable[str]:
        if n <= 0:
            # Exactly one sequence of length 0.
            yield ()
            return

        # Generate sequences of NoOp + Subcombinations(n - 1).
        subcombinations = helper(n - 1)
        for subcombination in subcombinations:
            yield ('NoOp', *subcombination)

        # Generate sequences of the form:
        #     Push(x) + Subcombinations(a) + Pop(x) + Subcombinations(b),
        # where a >= 0, b >= 0, and a + b = (length - 2).
        if n >= 2:
            for a, b in yield_sum_splits(n - 2):
                a_sub = helper(a)
                b_sub = helper(b)

                # Use itertools.product when using yield.
                # Nested for loops would omit some outputs, strangely.
                for a_part, b_part in itertools.product(a_sub, b_sub):
                    i = next(counter)
                    pu_op = f'Push({i})'
                    po_op = f'Pop({i})'
                    yield (pu_op, *a_part, po_op, *b_part)

    yield from helper(length)
```